# Parse Lotus Notes clipboard link with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lotus-notes, lxml.html

I'm trying to parse a Lotus Notes document link (taken from the clipboard) to convert it to a `notes://` URL/URI. From the clipboard options, it appears that getting data from a text format is the easier way to convert. However, the link looks like a really badly-formed XML, and lxml is losing information when parsing.

```
data = """Name - Enc: Injeção
<NDL>
<REPLICA 83257B7B:00608A81>
<VIEW OFDCBCE5C7:007D345D-ON882572F4:00650240>
<NOTE OFD18FCA06:36A9EDA2-ON83257F6A:004E31C1>
<HINT>CN=SERV101/OU=RJ/OU=C/O=Company</HINT>
<REM>Database 'Name', View 'Inbox', Document 'Enc: Injeção'</REM>
</NDL>
"""
from lxml import html, etree
title, ndl = html.fragments_fromstring(data)
replica = ndl[0]
view = replica[0]
print replica.attrib
print view.attrib
print html.tostring(ndl)
```

This prints:

```
{}
{'ofdcbce5c7:007d345d-on882572f4:00650240': ''}
<ndl>
<replica>
<view ofdcbce5c7:007d345d-on882572f4:00650240>
<note ofd18fca06:36a9eda2-on83257f6a:004e31c1>
<hint>CN=SERV101/OU=RJ/OU=C/O=Company</hint>
<rem>Database 'Name', View 'Inbox', Document 'Enc: Inje&#195;&#167;&#195;&#163;o'</rem>
</note></view></replica></ndl>
```

So, I'm losing information from the `REPLICA` tag, even though I still get some from the `VIEW` one (I suspect somehow the hyphen may make the difference here).

So, is there a way to get all the data with lxml or must I revert back to RegExp?

Environment info:

- Windows 7, 64-bit
- Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (32-bit)
- LXML 3.4.4

Comment: What version of Lotus Notes are you using? I was under the impression that recent versions were supposed to be putting the notes:// URL onto the clipboard as one of the alternate formats. (Come to think of it, that might only be for drag-drop operations. How are you putting the data on the clipboard.)

Comment: Lotus Notes 8.5.3. I'm copying the link by right-clicking the document and selecting "Copy as Document Link".

Answer (score 0):

You might find [*bs4*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) better:

```
data = """Name - Enc: Injeção
<NDL>
<REPLICA 83257B7B:00608A81>
<VIEW OFDCBCE5C7:007D345D-ON882572F4:00650240>
<NOTE OFD18FCA06:36A9EDA2-ON83257F6A:004E31C1>
<HINT>CN=SERV101/OU=RJ/OU=C/O=Company</HINT>
<REM>Database 'Name', View 'Inbox', Document 'Enc: Injeção'</REM>
</NDL>
"""
from lxml.etree import fromstring, HTMLParser
xml = fromstring(data, HTMLParser())
r = xml.xpath("//replica")


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

title = next(soup.find("ndl").previous_elements)
print(title)
print(soup.find("replica").attrs)
print(soup.find("view"))
```

Which gives you:

```
Name - Enc: Injeção

{u'83257b7b:00608a81': ''}
view ofdcbce5c7:007d345d-on882572f4:00650240="">
<note ofd18fca06:36a9eda2-on83257f6a:004e31c1="">
<hint>CN=SERV101/OU=RJ/OU=C/O=Company</hint>
<rem>Database 'Name', View 'Inbox', Document 'Enc: Injeção'</rem>
</note></view>
```